# Is there a generic way to decompose the free comonad over a failure monad into a “values stream and final error”?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monads, comonad

The [`Cofree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html) comonad is useful for iterating partial functions in a way that's polymorphic on the error type. Its [`coiter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Comonad-Cofree.html#v:coiter) resembles `forM`-looping in an error monad, but it gathers the produced values in a pure/lazy manner and you only see an error at the end, down in the data struct.

For example, `Cofree Identity` (no failure permitted!) is an infinite stream, whereas `Cofree Maybe` is isomorphic to [`NonEmpty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.18.1/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html), and `Cofree (Either e) a` is basically `(NonEmpty a, e)` (list of successfull-iteration values plus an error that occurs at the end).

Now I wonder what's the best way to evaluate the results, without specific pattern-matching on a single error monad. Extracting all the *values* is very easy thanks to the `Foldable` instance (e.g. `toList`), but I'm not sure how to best get hold of the *errors*. It would be possible to exploit `Foldable` for that to just get *rid* of the values and leave the error part:

```
vals'n'err :: (Monad m, Foldable m)
          => Cofree m a -> (NonEmpty a, (m ()))
vals'n'err (a :< q) = case toList q of
        [] -> (a:|[], const () <$> q)
        l  -> first (pure a<>)
           $ foldr1 (\(bs,e) (cs,f) -> (bs<>cs, e>>f)) $ vals'n'err<$>l
```

but this feels a bit hackish. Is there a better solution?

Comment: From a constructive POV getting `(NonEmpty a, e)` from `Cofree (Either e) a` doesn't make much sense to me, since `Cofree` is a coinductive type and it's perfectly OK for a `Cofree (Either e) a` to be an infinite stream interleaved by `Right`s, but you promise to always return an `e`. No surprise `vals'n'err` feels hackish.

Comment: @user3237465: yeah. So what signature would you propose?

Comment: I don't see a problem to solve here. Consuming a `Cofree (Either e) a` in a streaming fashion and stopping on `Left` is a common and sensible way to go, why risk to get an uncatchable leaking bottom of type `e`?

Comment: @user3237465: because this is not polymorphic on the error monad, and the manual recursion is totally awkward when working from a REPL / IHaskell.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is bad transformation for large streams, because you can have space leak by laziness. But for small streams it maybe usable.

We can divide this transformation on two:

```
vals :: Foldable f => Cofree f a -> NonEmpty a
vals = NonEmpty.fromList . Foldable.toList

err :: Monad m => Cofree m a -> m b
err (_ :< m) = m >>= err
```

And then combine together:

```
vals'n'err :: (Monad m, Foldable m) => Cofree m a -> (NonEmpty a, m b)
vals'n'err w = (vals w, err w)
```

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks!

Comment: `vals` should surely use `foldMap1`.

Comment: @dfeuer Maybe, but  instance `Foldable1 (Cofree f)` has constraint `Foldable1 f`. This will narrow the set of possible types. On the other hand I do not understand such the constraint, why not `instance Foldable f => Foldable1 (Cofree f)`.

Comment: that is indeed surprising.